# Way to let users wait in a queue until there is enough Free RAM on server

Tags: php, queue

What is the best way to setup a web application to check free RAM on the server and keep users into a waiting queue until sufficient RAM is available again?

I think fetching free RAM on server would only be possible using exec(), right?

I want to enforce this system in my web application as my web application makes use of a lot of RAM and during high traffic i dont want my server to get halted.

Thanks.

Comment: @Dan Grossman, I think you should make that an answer, and I'll upvote.

Comment: @Dan Grossman this is an answer…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should separate the part of your code that handles web requests and the part that does the resource-intensive work. When you get the web request, put the job into a queue, which separate processes pull jobs off of and do the work. You can have the user on the webpage poll your server every X seconds with AJAX until their job has been processed then update their page.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. In terms of actual programming, what would be the best way to manage such a queue. Databases?

Comment: There are specialized solutions for work queues, but for most applications, a database table would work fine.

Comment: I cannot think of any other way than an database. what can be an fair alternative?

Comment: http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/ http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/jms/fund.html http://memcachedb.org/memcacheq/